# Pie chart charts_flutter change on selection

Tags: flutter, dart, pie-chart

I created pie-chart like this with the charts_flutter. The text widget changes on chart selection with the `selectionModels->changedListener`.

So I have a question, is there a way to change the color or the arcWidth of the selected item, that a user can see, which item he selected. Or there exists another way how to show a user selected item?

[image]

Here is the code

```
class OutcomeChart extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _OutcomeChartState createState() => _OutcomeChartState();

  Widget _buildLabel({String label, double money}) {
    return Center(
      child: SizedBox(
        width: 150,
        child: Text(
          '$label\n$money',
          overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class _OutcomeChartState extends State<OutcomeChart> {
  String _categoryName = '';
  double _money = 0;

  List<charts.Series<Map, dynamic>> _createSampleData(List<Map> data) {
    return [
      new charts.Series<Map, dynamic>(
        id: 'Sales',
        domainFn: (Map item, _) => item['category_id'],
        measureFn: (Map item, _) => item['money'],
        data: data,
      )
    ];
  }

  void _onSelectionChanged(charts.SelectionModel model) {
    if (model.hasDatumSelection) {
      final selectedDatum = model.selectedDatum.first;

      setState(() {
        _categoryName = selectedDatum.datum['category_name'];
        _money = selectedDatum.datum['money'].toDouble();
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      child: SizedBox(
        height: 450,
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            BlocBuilder<HomePageBloc, HomePageState>(
              builder: (context, state) {
                var data = state is HomePageDataLoaded
                    ? state.outcome
                    : <Map<dynamic, dynamic>>[];

                var widgets = <Widget>[
                  charts.PieChart(
                    _createSampleData(data),
                    defaultInteractions: true,
                    animate: false,
                    behaviors: [
                      new charts.SelectNearest(),
                      charts.DomainHighlighter(),
                    ],
                    selectionModels: [
                      charts.SelectionModelConfig(
                        type: charts.SelectionModelType.info,
                        changedListener: _onSelectionChanged,
                      )
                    ],
                    defaultRenderer: charts.ArcRendererConfig(
                      arcWidth: 60,
                    ),
                  )
                ];

                if (0 == _money) {
                  var sum = 0;
                  data
                      .map((e) => e['money'])
                      .forEach((element) => sum += element);
                  widgets.add(widget._buildLabel(money: sum.toDouble(), label: 'All'));
                } else {
                  widgets.add(
                      widget._buildLabel(money: _money, label: _categoryName));
                }

                return Stack(children: widgets);
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Ihor, were you able to find an answer to this one?

Comment: @max.kuzmentsov no, with this package. I go with https://pub.dev/packages/fl_chart

Comment: you could probably answer your own question with this response, fl_chart seems to work better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't find how to do it with the charts_flutter library, so I change it to the [fl_chart](https://pub.dev/packages/fl_chart). And [here](https://github.com/imaNNeoFighT/fl_chart/blob/master/repo_files/documentations/pie_chart.md#sample-2-source-code) you can find some examples.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a behavior, like this:

```
behaviors: [
    new charts.InitialSelection(selectedDataConfig: [
      new charts.SeriesDatumConfig<String>('Purchases', 'Eating Out'),
    ]),
    new charts.DomainHighlighter(),
  ],
```

Comment: How to programatically select or highlight pie chart slice?
For example- I am not using default legend of pie chart because of some other requirements and I am using  my own pie chart legend. On click of any legend value, I want to highlight or select pie slice associated with that value.